# Can we use 555 timer in automotive electronic circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, voltage-regulator, filter, 555

Can we use 555 timer IC in autmotive electronics design?
If not then please suggest an IC in order to create dealy at laod side.

Comment: what is `dealy at laod side`

Comment: Why not? Pick one for automotive application and use it

Comment: @jsotola : it is 2 leds in sereis with V( typ)=2.8V, and would like to provide 10 microsec delay between them.

Comment: Not without protection. 'Automotive' means survive sustained -12v or +24v, and transient +160v, for bad jumpstarting and alternator load dump respectively. Otherwise, go for it.

Comment: You haven't seen my output yet

Comment: @Neil_UK does it really mean that? Usually, automotive parts means AEC-Q100, which puts some heavy constraints on temperature operating range, electrostatic discharge and stuff like that, but I doubt automotive ICs can really withstand +160V transients, or even 24V, can they?

Comment: @NSR **edit** your question to include the information about the LEDs and the order of delay. This makes a **big** difference. What currents do these LEDs draw?

Answer (score 1):

In principle you CAN use anything, as long as it fits within the specifications for your automobile device/part.

Note for the NE555 there is a similar SE555 [See example from TI](http://www.ti.com/product/SE555), which is suitable for military purposes (with disclamer), which has increased specifications.